# Deluge is not connecting to daemon on server despite working from another machine

Tags: server, deluge

I'm running the Deluge daemon on a server on my home network, and would like to be able to connect with both my desktop and my laptop.

- Laptop: *Ubuntu 16.04, Deluge 1.3.12*
- Desktop: *Ubuntu 14.04, Deluge 1.3.6*
- Server: *Mythbuntu 14.04, Deluge 1.3.6*

Connecting through both `deluge-console` and the GUI work on the Desktop.

Entering the same information *(IP, port, user, and password)* on the Laptop does not discover a connection. In the GUI, there is still a grey X in Connection Manager; when attempting to connect through the console, no information is output, the console just remains unconnected. I have disconnected and reconnected the desktop to confirm that all of the daemon information is correct.

I've rolled back the laptop's version of deluge to 1.3.6 to see if there was a version incompatibility, but this didn't fix the problem. Deluged is running as my normal user (not a new deluge user).

Comment: This is unlikely to be a Deluge issue, I would suggest there is something else going on with your laptop. You will need to see if you can ping and telnet to the daemon. I am not sure if it will identify the issue but you can enable deluge debug logs from both client and daemon.

Comment: It also it prudent to update Deluge to the latest version, 1.3.12, as 1.3.6 is ancient and huge numbers of other fixes have been made since that release...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "fixed" this problem by upgrading Deluge on the server to 1.3.12. This can be done with the Deluge PPA [Guide here.](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing/Linux/Ubuntu#AddDelugePPARepository)

> **Deluge PPA Repository**
>
> The ​Deluge PPA contains the latest Deluge releases for Ubuntu.
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deluge-team/ppa
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install deluge
> ```

Comment: This reminds me that for security SSLv3 was disabled so now only uses TLS in later versions of Deluge (also TLS forced in openssl) and likely the reason for not connecting.

Comment: For reference this is the relevant ticket: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/2555

Comment: A client running 1.3.6 will connect to a server running 1.3.12, but not vice-versa, it appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Remote Connections` for the daemon, from the Deluge [Thinclient Guide](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient#EnableRemoteConnection):

> Using the Console in command-line mode, set the allow_remote option and then verify with these commands:
>
> `deluge-console "config -s allow_remote True"`
>
> `deluge-console "config allow_remote"`
>
> If you are running deluged under another user (e.g. deluge) you will need to temporarily login as that user to enable deluge-console to access that daemon's config:
>
> `su --shell /bin/bash --login deluge`
>
> Alternatively you can edit core.conf (deluged must not be running) in the config and change allow_remote from false to true.

Comment: I don't believe that this could be the problem, since I can connect remotely. However, I changed allow_remote to true on the laptop just in case, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You didn't say you could connect remotely

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear from the fact that I can connect from the desktop to the server. I've edited to make it clearer.

Comment: It was not clear, I have updated the question for clarity