# Deluge can't connect to remote seedbox

Tags: remote-access, deluge, torrent-client

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Deluge 1.3.13 (from deluge-team PPA) but I can't connect to my remote seedbox.

I'm able to ping remote hostname.
I can telnet remote hostname and port.

```
$ telnet remote.dom 12345
Trying 12.34.56.7...
Connected to remote.dom.
```

I can connect using deluge-console with no error. I think that means successfully connected.

```
$ deluge-console "connect remote.dom:12345 username password"
```

When I open Deluge's Connection Manager, status with the remote seedbox is marked with cross and I can't connect.

I have tried Deluge on my Windows 7 virtual machine (VirtualBox installed on the same computer as above) and everything is working fine. I guess the problem is maybe in some missing service/component on my Ubuntu. What do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this question on Ask Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/a/792107/17397 and this is the answer from the Deluge developer: "for security SSLv3 was disabled so now only uses TLS in later versions of Deluge (also TLS forced in openssl) and likely the reason for not connecting." [Cas]

It seems newer version of daemon is backward compatible with older clients but not the opposite way.

"A client running 1.3.6 will connect to a server running 1.3.12, but not vice-versa" [alex_d]

I asked my seedbox provider to upgrade the daemon on their server and that solved this issue. Now I can connect from my Deluge (v1.3.13) thin client on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to the Deluge daemon (v1.3.13).