# deluge-console keeps disconnecting from remote daemon

Tags: kubuntu, bittorrent, raspberrypi, deluge

I have setup Deluge Daemon (with Web UI) on a RaspberryPi with `allow_remote=True`.

Afterwards I installed Deluge on Windows 10 and ran

```
sudo apt-get install deluge
sudo apt-get install deluge-console
```

on a Kubuntu virtual machine.

When I start the client from Windows, I can connect without a problem and also get the green indicator that the daemon is up and running. However, when I try to connect to the same daemon from Kubuntu the status indicator shows that the daemon is offline.

I ran `deluge-console -L info` and after `connect <ip:port> <remote_user> <password>` I get the following:

```
[INFO    ] 22:17:10 ui:121 Deluge ui 1.3.12
[INFO    ] 22:17:10 ui:124 Starting console ui..
[INFO    ] 22:17:10 client:217 Connecting to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846..
[WARNING ] 22:17:10 client:220 Connection to daemon at 127.0.0.1:58846 failed: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
[INFO    ] 22:17:23 client:217 Connecting to daemon at <ip>:<port>..
[INFO    ] 22:17:23 client:121 Connected to daemon at <ip>:<port>..
[INFO    ] 22:17:23 client:224 Connection lost to daemon at <ip>:<port> reason: Connection was closed cleanly.
```

Can someone please point me what am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
When I run `deluged --version` I get the following output:

```
deluged: 1.3.3
libtorrent: 0.15.10.0
```

On both Windows machine and Kubuntu virtual machine the version of the client is `1.3.12`.

If it helps, I followed the install instructions from [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cARrPUryp-X37QZy29hCMA3zVddDCg4NmBCIZEflel8/edit). But unfortunately I don't know where the daemon logs the output.

Comment: What versions is the daemon? Make sure you have updated to latest version of Deluge. You need to have `debug` logging on both client and daemon to understand why it's not connecting.

Comment: @Cas, thank you for the comment; I've updated the question.

Comment: Then you need to see this answer and my comment:  http://askubuntu.com/a/792107/8570

Comment: @Cas, I waited for the newest version from the official repository and it worked. Please add your comment as an answer so I could mark it as the right answer.